# Send iOS push notifications to multiple devices

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

This might be already answered but my eyes are bleeding with so much information. I've managed to use the *notnoop* notification project and is has been pretty good until the point of sending push notifications to multiple devices.

I'm debugging and showing the device's deviceToken through XCode and inserting it manually. Obviously this is not a solution because I'm using it with the Sandbox and implementing it in delivered app is not working.

So now is where I'm asking myself how to "automatize" the process of registering the device's deviceTokens on the server and sending the push notification message to all of them.

I've been thinking on creating a .jsp and passing the deviceTokens through POST, make an INSERT on the MySQL database and then, when wanting to send a push notification, pick up every deviceToken and then send the push notifications.

I can't believe this isn't already explained anywhere or maybe I'm too confused at this point to see it.

Actually, my code is the following:

```
import com.notnoop.apns.APNS;
import com.notnoop.apns.ApnsService;

public class PushServiceTryout
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ApnsService service = APNS.newService()
                .withCert("c:/fcertificates.p12", "1234")
                .withSandboxDestination()
                .build();
        String msg = "Hello! Push notification test!";          
        String payload = APNS.newPayload().alertBody(msg).build();
        //Obviously fake
        String token = "123456789012345678901234567890abcabcabcacbabcbacbacb";
        service.push(token, payload);
        System.out.println("Notification sent");
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Well, you can write a server yourself that will get the token from your devices. Alternatively, you can use a service that does that for you (Like Boxcar, Urban Airship, etc).

Comment: Thank you. I finally made two .jsp that wait and process this problem. I will paste the code here. Thanks anyway,

Answer (score 1):

I finally did this in .jsp. Here it is the source if anyone needs it:

Index.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%
    System.out.println(" *** DEBUG *** On push notifications -menu- \n");

    Connection conn = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    // Connection parameters
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apns";
    String user = "root";
    String passwd = "";

    // ******** Connection procedure ********
    String connectionstatus="";
    try
    {
        Class.forName(driver);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,passwd);
    } catch (Exception ex){
        connectionstatus=ex.toString();
    }
    connectionstatus="connected to the DB!";
    if(conn.isClosed())
    {
        connectionstatus="NOT connected to the DB. Check URL, DB connectivity...";
    }
    //******** END of the connetion procedure ********

    statement = conn.createStatement();

    // ******** TABLE with inserted deviceTokens on the DB ********
    String querytotal="SELECT * from devicetokens";
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(querytotal);

    out.println("The following DeviceTokens are saved on the DB: " + "<BR>");
    out.println("<table border=2>");
    while(resultSet.next())
    {
        out.println("<tr>");
        out.println("<td>" + resultSet.getString("id") + "</td>");
        out.println("<td>" + resultSet.getString("devicetoken") + "</td>");
        out.println("</tr>");
        System.out.println(" *** DEBUG *** " + resultSet.getString("id") + " -> " + resultSet.getString("devicetoken"));
    }
    out.println("</table>");
    // ******** END of the table with saved deviceTokens ********

    // ------> Receiving the deviceToken from the device! <------
    String devtoken = request.getParameter("devtoken");

    boolean flag = false;
    if(devtoken == null)
    {
        System.out.println("Just reloaded the page? Recently running the server? Because no devtoken has been received.");
        flag = true;    // Prevents inserting a "null" devtoken into the DB. FLAG up
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The received deviceToken is: " + devtoken);
        // Insert deviceToken into the DB
        String queryinsert="INSERT INTO devicetokens(devicetoken) VALUES ('" + devtoken + "')";
        statement = conn.createStatement();
        statement.execute(queryinsert);

        // Show inserted deviceTokens on the DB
        String queryshow="SELECT * from devicetokens";
        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(queryshow);
    }
%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Push menu</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Show if you're connected to the database or not -->
        <h1>You are <%=connectionstatus%></h1>
        <form action="sendpush.jsp" method="POST">
            <label><b>.p12 certificate</b> path</label> <input type="file" name="path"> <br>
            <label> Certificate password</label> <input type="text" name="password"> <br>
            <!-- Offer the a textarea for the user and handle the maxlength -->
            <label>Message to be sent:</label> <input type="text" name="message" size="60" maxlength="110" onkeyup="total.value = 110 - this.value.length">
                <input type="text" name="total" size="3" maxlength="3" disabled>
            <input type="submit" value="Send push notification"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

sendpush.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*,com.notnoop.apns.APNS,com.notnoop.apns.ApnsService,java.util.List,java.util.ArrayList,java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%
    System.out.println(" *** DEBUG *** On sending push notifications \n");

// ************ APNS settings **************
    String cpath = request.getParameter("path");    // Path with the located .p12 file
    String cpasswd = request.getParameter("password");  // Certificate's password

    ApnsService service = APNS.newService()
    .withCert("c:/fcertificates.p12", "1234")
    // In case we're on developer environment use .withSandboxdestination()
    .withSandboxDestination()
    // In case we're on production environment (final app ready to be delivered on the App Store) use .withProductionDestination()
    //.withProductionDestination()
    .build();

    String msg = request.getParameter("message");   // Message that user wants to deliver to devices    
    String payload = APNS.newPayload()
    .alertBody(msg)
    .badge(0)
    .sound("default")
    .build();   

// ***************** END of APNS settings ***************
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    // Connection parameters
    String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apns";
    String user = "root";
    String passwd = "";

    // ******** Connection procedure ********
    String message="";
    try
    {
        Class.forName(driver);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,passwd);
    } catch (Exception ex){
        message=ex.toString();
    }

    message="Connected!";
    if(conn.isClosed()){
        message="Disconnected";
    }
    //******** END of the connetion procedure ********

    // Executing the query
    statement = conn.createStatement();

    // Retrieve all the deviceTokens from DB
    String queryshow = "SELECT devicetoken from devicetokens";
    resultSet = statement.executeQuery(queryshow);

    List<String> listtokens = new ArrayList<String>();  // A List<> to play with the deviceTokens

    while(resultSet.next())
    {
        out.println("A push notification is going to be sent to the following devicetoken " + resultSet.getString("devicetoken") + "<BR>"); // Show the deviceToken
        listtokens.add(resultSet.getString("devicetoken")); // Add it to the List of deviceTokens
        System.out.println(" *** DEBUG *** Added " + resultSet.getString("devicetoken") + " to the List<>");    // Show in console
    }

%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Notification sent...</title>
    </head>
    <body>        
        <%
        Iterator it = listtokens.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext()) // Send the push notification to the deviceTokens on the List<> 
        {
            String finaltoken = (String)it.next();
            service.push(finaltoken, payload);
            out.println("Push notification sent to devicetoken: " + finaltoken + "<BR>");
            System.out.println(" *** DEBUG *** Push notification sent to devicetoken: " + finaltoken);
        }
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `"It's not the best code in the world but hope you enjoy it."` Probably not a comment you want to be adding so i have removed

Comment: Did you have the jar file in the same folder? I got this error, Only a type can be imported. com.notnoop.apns.ApnsService resolves to a package